# What's going wrong when counting words in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, frequency

I  wrote a code to split words and to count frequencies. However, the results don't match what a found when tried a CTRL + F in my csv file. What is wrong?

The

```
split = df.text.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

The results:

```
de                          3090
e                           2178
a                           2136
o                           1957
do                          1600
que                         1457
para                        1258
da                          1179
com                          997
em                           963
```

The word 'que', for example, has 1471 resuls in CSV. Otherwise, the word 'de' has 2757.

Comment: Howdo you read a dataframe?

Comment: ```
df_total = pd.read_csv('tweets.csv')
df = df_total[['text']]
```

Comment: No columns in CSV except 'text'?

Comment: There is several columns, but I just want this one.

Comment: What I'm trying to figure is maybe other columns affect word count in a csv?

Comment: I've created another dataframe only with two columns.